# Horizontal iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe

So, I am having trouble with iframes, I included in the dropdown navigation and the alignment of these iframes according to the navigation length, but its going across the horizontal way.

I am quite new to HTML and don't know how to solve this. I have attached the picture too as a reference. I want the result on the same page so I don't have to scroll.

[image]

Comment: they say a picture is worth a thousand words ... not here ... post some code

Comment: Try something like `iframe {display: inline-block;}` in your css. If it works you have a starting point.